# Validation rule on formula field with or

Tags: validation, validation-rule, administration

I have a formula field and a text field and I'm trying to figure out how to write the validation rule, so the logic is:

Start_Date__c should not blank AND formula_field__c should not have EITHER `start` or `end`

I try to write something like this but its not working:

```
AND(
   ISBLANK(Start_Date__c ),
   NOT(CONTAINS(formula_field__c , "start")),
   OR (NOT(CONTAINS(formula_field__c , "end")))
)
```

Comment: Is the criteria that `Start_Date__c` should not be blank if `formula_field__c` is either "start" or "end"?

Comment: `start_date__c` should NOT be blank `AND` `formula_field__c` should NOT be either `start` or `end`

Comment: Please edit your question to give exact examples of what is and is not acceptable. "EITHER"..."You keep using that word. I do not think it means what you think it means." (Or I don't think it means what you think it means.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is not very clear; my initial answer was about "exclusive-or" logic. Per your comments, you actually want to prohibit the values "start" and "end" in the field `formula_field__c` and prohibit `Start_Date__c` from being blank.

Since a Validation Rule fires when it evaluates to TRUE, the existing structure of your Rule is incorrect. You would want an outer `OR()`, with three parameters expressing the three conditions you do not want to allow.

```
OR(
    ISBLANK(Start_Date__c ),
    CONTAINS(formula_field__c , "start"),
    CONTAINS(formula_field__c , "end")
)
```

Comment: thanks David, but the VR did not work, I have a formula field `start` and `start_date__c` some value so based on, it should have throw me an error but it did not.

Comment: @NickKahn Are you saying that one of the fields is actually called "start" and not "formula_field__c"?

Comment: I meant value so, what I meant is that formula_field__c has value which can be `start` or `end` depends.

Comment: @NickKahn Your question seemed to be about how to write a "A but not B" condition in formula language, which is what I have answered. I really don't know what you're asking now. Please edit your question to clarify.

Comment: Are you saying you want to compare the value of `formula_field__c` to _some other field_ called `start`?

Comment: no, what i'm saying is that formula_field__c value can be either `start` or `end` it depends on the record change.

Comment: Nick, I'm sorry, but I have no idea what you're asking me.

Comment: `start_date__c` should NOT be blank `AND` `formula_field__c` should NOT be either `start` or `end`

Comment: @NickKahn : Your last two comments (separated by David's one comment) are contradictory.  Please edit your question and give exact examples of what is and is not acceptable.

Answer (score 1):

I guess it should be

```
AND(
   ISBLANK(Start_Date__c ),
   OR((CONTAINS(formula_field__c , 'start'), CONTAINS(formula_field__c , 'end'))
)
```

Please note `CONTAINS` check is case sensitive.

Comment: sorry, did not work, noted on case-sensitive.

Comment: I set up new date field, new text formula field, and a validation rule that looks like this one, and it works for me - as I understand the question.

Comment: @Moonpie That's what I understood. Works for me as well. Maybe the ask is conveyed incorrectly.

Comment: ...and the ask was conveyed incorrectly.  I was going to remove my upvote - nothing against you, just so future visitors might be less confused.  But now that I think about it, unless/until the original question is edited so that it is more clear, thus making it more obvious that David's answer is the correct one, I am going to leave my upvote.